# Create Transaction with context and sql command, C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I would like to create one transaction of two saves: one via entity framework's context and the other using sql command.

How do i get the connection of one, pass it to the other and create a transaction?

For example:

```
var ctx = ApplicationContext();
var tr = ctx.Transaction.where(x=>x.id=1);
tr.status = 5;
ctx.SaveChanges();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
 {
   using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
   { //set query and params
     connection.Open();
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

Comment: What versione of EntityFramework are you using here?

Comment: Entity Framework 6

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test it at the moment, but you can look at the 
[`Database property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=vs.113).aspx) of the DbContext. Here you can find properties and methods to get a transaction object and the connection itself.

You can use them for your command

```
var ctx = ApplicationContext();
using(var tr = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    // Not sure if at this point the connection is still open
    // or not disposed. You need to experiment here.

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, ctx.Database.Connection))
    {
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         tr.Commit();
    }
}
```

But at this point you will notice the existence of a method called [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(System.String,System.Object[])) that probably could simplify again the code

Comment: I will try that, thanks. Found a slightly different answer here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 which creates the connection first